# How do I get input for an array from a user in C programming?

Tags: c, arrays, input

I am new to C and I've run into a bit of a problem when it comes to user input for an array.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, i;
    int score [n];
    printf("Number of scores: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
       printf("score: ");
       scanf("%d", &score[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It does not matter what value I set for n. It always prompts the user 4 times.

Comment: Did you notice that n is uninitialized? How big should the score[n] array be?

Comment: Some compilers print a warning if a variable is used without initialization. You should turn on warnings as far as possible.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you must change this:

```
/* bad */
int score [n];
printf("Number of scores: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
```

into this

```
/* good */
printf("Number of scores: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
int score [n];
```

This since C executes code from top to bottom like when you are reading a book. It will not "double back" a few rows above and fill in `n` once it has been entered by the user. At the point where you declare `int score [n]`, `n` must already be known.

Comment: Except in the case the syntax of C would have changed recently, this is not true. For allocating an array without knowing the size when you enter into a function, you have to allocate it with `malloc()`.

Comment: @PierreFrançois Except the year 1999 when this feature (variable-length array) was introduced is not "recently", it's 21 years ago. Time to study C again: the language was revised in 1995, 1999, 2011 and 2017.

Comment: Thank you so much, Lundin. This was indeed a valuable lesson.

Answer (score 1):

If your using an array with unknown size during compilation, I would suggest using memory allocation. So the user determines the array size while running the program.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, i;
    int *score;
    printf("Number of scores: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    score = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
       printf("score: ");
       scanf("%d", &score[i]);
    }
    free(score)
    return 0;
}
```

The `malloc` function allocates memory with the size of `n` and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.